# How can I parse GHC core?

Tags: haskell, ghc

I am trying to parse ghc core code obtained from running `ghc -c -ddump-simpl myfile.hs`.

I know [`extcore`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/extcore) and [`core`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/core) libraries are my options.

I am looking for a simple example depicting the use of these libraries.

[EDIT] Parsing result should be a data structure from which it should be easy to trace different paths a function can take.

Consider a simple `not` function

```
not True = False
not False = True
```

GHC will turn this into case expressions (consider output from `ghc -c -ddump-simple` only). I am looking to parse this output of GHC core.

Comment: I think this is a good question and the answer would be interesting to me as well - I know: the caption is asking for an tutorial and that is technically no ok on SO - on the other hand SO is often extremely unfriendly so I feel that Haskell has it's own kind of nicer community ;) - in this case: a example would IMO be a valuable addition for further reference (so I am voting for reopen) -- I really wish moderators (not active on the subtopic) would wait a bit before force-closing questions (if it will turn out in spam **then** close it please)

Comment: @Carsten: Missing documentation/examples is a deficit of the library or program and should be filed as an issue there instead. I think this question is _too broad_, by the way, since the expected parsing result and other specifications are missing. Also, if you think that a question should be on-topic and was closed by a moderator in error, make sure to post on [meta], not in a comment (but feel free to link to the meta-discussion in a comment).

Comment: @Zeta I rarely step into that ant nest (MSO) - I just thought that I should somehow explain my vote to reopen

Comment: The edit still doesn't state what the result of the parser should be. Should it translate back to regular Haskell code (which probably isn't feasible), just checked for syntactic correctness, parsed into some kind of user defined ADT?

Comment: Assuming we are writing a parser in haskell, the result would be a data structure which will represent all possible execution paths of the program. 
In this particular case it will be some sort of tree which of height one with one branch for true and the other one for false

Comment: `-ddump-simpl` output is designed for human consumption rather than machine consumption (yes, I know it's still not that easy to read!) I would suggest getting your hands on the Core through the GHC API instead.

Comment: I'm pretty sure this exact same question was asked some time ago and the "final answer" was: currently there's no way to parse it.

Answer (score 4):

I think the easiest way is to forego these external Core libraries and just use GHC as a library directly. Based on [this example from the Haskell wiki](https://wiki.haskell.org/GHC/As_a_library), we can make a simple function that turns a module into Core:

```
import GHC
import GHC.Paths (libdir)
import HscTypes (mg_binds)
import CoreSyn
import DynFlags
import Control.Monad ((<=<))

compileToCore :: String -> IO [CoreBind]
compileToCore modName = runGhc (Just libdir) $ do
    setSessionDynFlags =<< getSessionDynFlags
    target <- guessTarget (modName ++ ".hs") Nothing
    setTargets [target]
    load LoadAllTargets
    ds <- desugarModule <=< typecheckModule <=< parseModule <=< getModSummary $ mkModuleName modName
    return $ mg_binds . coreModule $ ds
```

Here's a silly example usage that processes its output to count the number of cases:

```
-- Silly example function that analyzes Core
countCases :: [CoreBind] -> Int
countCases = sum . map countBind
  where
    countBind (NonRec _ e) = countExpr e
    countBind (Rec bs) = sum . map (countExpr . snd) $ bs

    countExpr (Case e _ _ alts) = countExpr e + sum (map countAlt alts)
    countExpr (App f e) = countExpr f + countExpr e
    countExpr (Lam _ e) = countExpr e
    countExpr (Let b e) = countBind b + countExpr e
    countExpr (Cast e _) = countExpr e
    countExpr (Tick _ e) = countExpr e
    countExpr _ = 0

    countAlt (_, _, rhs) = 1 + countExpr rhs
```

Let's run it on your example:

```
main :: IO ()
main = do
   core <- compileToCore "MyNot"
   print $ countCases core
```

This outputs 2, as expected.

Comment: Note that the code as given will create `.hi` and `.o` files. You can probably change the `dflags` to omit that.

Comment: This example is quite useful. @Cactus can you share a couple of links from where I can learn more about GHC core library?